# create custom profile in iphone

Tags: iphone

can i create a custom or new profile like silent or outdoor in iphone through iphone sdk..?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "profile", can you elaborate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not at all possible. In fact the concept of Profiles does not exist in iPhone.